# joinPoint of @Around( AOP ) proceeds but doesn't return result

Tags: spring-boot, aop

I use @Around to implement AOP with springboot. Like below

```java
@Around("cut()")
public void advice( ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint ) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("@Around start");
    proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    System.out.println("@Around end");
}
```

The joinPoint is my controller & The `"@Mylog"` is my custom annotation.Like below

```java
@MyLog
@RequestMapping("/log")
public String getLog() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("This is joinPoint");
    return "Hello World";
}
```

When I try to get route "/log" with browser, the information is printed as expected but nothing is returned to browser(I expect `"Hello World"` will be returned). Like below

```
@Around start
This is joinPoint
@Around end
```

Any advice?

Comment: Unless the controller is a @RestController, the String you are returning will be the name of a View, which will likely fail to resolve.
Can you provide the full code of the controller and advice classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not surprise you that if your around advice returns nothing (`void`) instead of the `proceed()` result, then in fact nothing is returned. ;-) How about this?

```java
@Around("cut()")
public Object advice(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("@Around start");
    try {
        return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println("@Around end");
    }
}
```